importing file on Jupter notebook
I'm trying to run data for the Kaggle competition on Jupter Notebook on Google Cloud AI, every time I try to access the Kaggle competition file jane-street-real-time-market-data-forecasting, however, I'm getting an error
import sys
sys.path.append('imported/kaggle/input/jane-street-real-time-market-data-forecasting/kaggle_evaluation/jane_street_inference_server.py')
from kaggle_evaluation.jane_street_inference_server import JSInferenceServer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kaggle_evaluation'

Everything is defined correctly,
please find the link here
https://3ca4a2895c6aced0-dot-us-central1.notebooks.googleusercontent.com/lab/tree/imported/jane-street-rmf-demo-submission-985fd555-1309-45b9-9db2-def394cb5c21.ipynb
even when trying to find the root file exist
import os  
# Define the dataset path dataset_path = "/"  
os.path.exists('dataset_path')  
>>> Output False

I expect to get the Kaggle data set working and the aggle_evaluation module working?
